# Source for wearing special clothing on Rosh Chodesh

Tags: minhag, clothing, rosh-chodesh-new-month

Is there a source for wearing somewhat festive clothes on Rosh Chodesh?

I have seen some people who hold this custom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.dailyhalacha.com/Display.asp?PageIndex=11&ClipID=967

[Kaf Hachayim 419:6](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14422&st=&pgnum=340) mentions it and the Vilna Gaon used to wear something special for Rosh Chodesh