# Rosh Chodesh at home

Tags: minhag, rosh-chodesh-new-month, home-house, parties-celebrations

How could one celebrate Rosh Chodesh at home and are there any customs like on Shabat (candles, bread, kiddush) or festivals (blowing shofar)?

Comment: Maybe wear nicer clothes and eat nicer food?

Comment: @DoubleAA, is that customary or prescribed? If so, I suggest you post an answer.

Answer (score 4):

You should have a bigger, nicer meal. (Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 419)

Add hallel in davening and *ya'aleh v'yavoh* in Shmoneh Esrei and bentching. (SA OC 422 and 424)

Some women have the custom of not doing *melacha*. (SA OC 417)

Other than that, not really.

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%94_%D7%A8%D7%91_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9_%D7%97%D7%95%D7%93%D7%A9#.D7.A7.D7.A0.D7.90

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8420/759

Answer (score 0):

I have dedicated sparkly slip on sandals for Rosh Chodesh. I generally look for the absence of the moon, blow my shofar, pray from my siddur, light a candle, have a tasty snack and a swallow of liquor. indulge for 30 mins or so.

I have slippers and Shabbos robes and comfy floor length dresses and scarves and whatnot dedicated for Rosh Chodesh and Havdalah and shabbat. Separation of the holy from the mundane is easy- rejoice and enjoy!

Comment: Welcome to MY! Would you tell us why would you need to sound the shofar?

Comment: also "the absence of a moon" is not necessarily enough to know when Rosh Chodesh is. You should look at a Jewish calendar (such as [this one from chabad.org](https://www.chabad.org/calendar/view/month_cdo/jewish/Jewish-Calendar.htm)) in order to know which day(s) is/are Rosh Chodesh.

Comment: Thanks Esther, I have Hebcal loaded on my phone and I believe in the rotation of the earth on its axis. I am pretty sure that the new month pushes through whether I observe it in the sky or not. Thanks for the warm welcome. Sounding the shofar isn't required, I can't be forced to do so. However, I enjoy the crisp, ear-splitting blow of my shofar and feel health and joy fill my lungs and spirit, so I utilize it as appropriate. I don't have an exact Torah reference, but I am pretty sure that shofar blowing for Rosh Chodesh is at least tolerated, if not a mitzvah.