# Should one be sure to have a bread meal on Rosh Chodesh?

Tags: bentching, rosh-chodesh-new-month, meal-seudah

Is there a source for the idea of specially having a bread meal on Rosh Chodesh so that one can say the special insertion for Rosh Chodesh in the grace after meals?

related: [Rosh Chodesh at home](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/65175/rosh-chodesh-at-home)

Comment: Just to be clear, answers that prescribe a bread meal but for any other reason are not what you seek?

Comment: not sure what you are exactly asking but the Mishna Brurah on 419:1 goes through this,and there is a very intrestimg Magen Avraham on this as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mishna Brurah commentary on [O.C. 419:1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40448&st=&pgnum=175) says that it is meritorious if one increases his feasting on Rosh Hodesh, however, it does not require eating foods that require Birkat Hamazon (i.e. bread), just an increase in the number of meals eaten as compared to a regular day, or an increase in the quantity.