Why is Rosh Chodesh—an early biblical holiday—celebrated with less fanfare than say Chanukah & Purim?
Tanach is replete with mention of Rosh Chodesh as a holiday, e.g., https://mg.alhatorah.org/Bemidbar/10.10 https://mg.alhatorah.org/Shemuel%20I/20.18
https://mg.alhatorah.org/Yeshayahu/1.13
https://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Tehillim/81/4#e0n6 ff.
Why isn't Rosh Chodesh given its due?

What is its due?

Some Chassisim make it a point to celebrate every day.

@DoubleAA For starters, a (more) celebratory posture and air. Attitudinal orientation aside, it would be manifest in, to give a few examples, better dress, celebratory meals/gatherings and perhaps taking off from work.

@Nahum For starters, I don't know anyone that wears better dress or takes off work on chanuka. Seudat Rosh Chodesh is indeed a longstanding halacha (and many do wear nicer clothes https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8420/759 ). You've listing assorted holiday practices but not why should they apply to Rosh Chodesh? Not every special day is the same.

@DoubleAA Tanach mentions it in the same breath as Shabbos and the moadim and it was clearly celebrated in style way back when, when and why did that lapse?

@DoubleAA Here's another RC custom (and Shabbos for that matter) that was in vogue during Tanachian times that seems to no longer be practiced: מלבי"ם מלכים ב ד':כ"ג
מדוע את הולכת אליו היום לא חודש, כי היה מנהגם ללכת אל איש האלהים בחדש ושבת

Rosh Chodesh is not on the listing of Moadim (Vayikra 23, Devarim 12, etc.). It has special korbanot, so we might best call it a mikdash/central holiday. Special Musaf but regular Shacharit. It may have been celebrated in style in the mikdash or in the sanhedrin, king's palace, etc. but for ordinary people nothing might have happened. There is no issur melacha (though consider https://wiki.jewishbooks.org.il/mediawiki/wiki/%D7%98%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%9F/%D7%9E%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94/%D7%9B%D7%91/%D7%91)

@DoubleAA I never claimed it is comparable issur melacha wise to the others. It shows up on the list in Numbers 28. The Talmud also refers to it as a Moed (e.g., https://shas.alhatorah.org/Full/Shevuot/10a.13#e0n6). Not sure why the king would be celebrating it if it was a temple thing or why the king would be different than the average person vis a vis this. In any event, that melachim verse clearly shows that the average person celebrated it as well.

@Nahum Yes I said it shows up Numbers 28. That's not a list of Moadim but the list of special Korbanot. Exactly my point above. The King wouldn't celebrate as an individual but as the King, the head of the court, the head of government.
